# cortex execute from RAM

Tags: cortex-m

I need execute firmware in RAM on a Cortex-M1 processor to erase and rewrite flash. I am using eclipse and launchpad's toolchain.
There is a similar question for MDK-ARM: [How do I execute a function from RAM on a Cortex-M3 (STM32)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044010/how-do-i-execute-a-function-from-ram-on-a-cortex-m3-stm32)

To run firmware from flash I configure linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 8K
    RAM (rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20004000, LENGTH = 16K
}
```

Then using JLink.exe utility I get:

```
J-Link>r
Reset delay: 0 ms
Reset type NORMAL: Resets core & peripherals via SYSRESETREQ & VECTRESET bit.
J-Link>mem32 0x00,2
00000000 = 20008000 00000101
J-Link>SetPC 0x0101
Info: Cortex-M: Debugger tries to set PC to odd value. Corrected register value from 0x00000101 to 0x00000100
J-Link>wreg MSP 0x20008000
MSP = 0x20008000
J-Link>halt
PC = 00000100, CycleCnt = 00000000
R0 = 00000300, R1 = 00000300, R2 = 00000010, R3 = 400A8000
R4 = 00001000, R5 = 2010108C, R6 = 00002040, R7 = 00000021
R8 = 00000000, R9 = 00000000, R10= 00000008, R11= 00000000
R12= 00000000
SP(R13)= 20008000, MSP= 20008000, PSP= 00000000, R14(LR) = FFFFFFFF
XPSR = 01000000: APSR = nzcvq, EPSR = 01000000, IPSR = 000 (NoException)
CFBP = 00000000, CONTROL = 00, FAULTMASK = 00, BASEPRI = 00, PRIMASK = 00
J-Link>s
00000100:  09 49              LDR     R1, [PC, #+0x24]
J-Link>s
00000102:  0A 4A              LDR     R2, [PC, #+0x28]
J-Link>s
00000104:  0A 4B              LDR     R3, [PC, #+0x28]
J-Link>s
00000106:  00 F0 07 F8        BL      #+0x0E
J-Link>s
00000118:  9B 1A              SUB     R3, R3, R2
J-Link>
```

Then I want to run firmware from RAM. For that I configure linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x20001000, LENGTH = 8K
    RAM (rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20004000, LENGTH = 16K
}
```

And here is I get error while executing that:

```
 J-Link>r
Reset delay: 0 ms
Reset type NORMAL: Resets core & peripherals via SYSRESETREQ & VECTRESET bit.
J-Link>loadbin milandr-template.bin 0x20001000
Downloading file [milandr-template.bin]...O.K.
J-Link>mem32 0x20001000,2
20001000 = 20008000 20001101
J-Link>SetPC 0x20001101
Info: Cortex-M: Debugger tries to set PC to odd value. Corrected register value from 0x20001101 to 0x20001100
J-Link>wreg MSP 0x20008000
MSP = 0x20008000
J-Link>halt
PC = 20001100, CycleCnt = 00000000
R0 = 00000300, R1 = 00000300, R2 = 00000010, R3 = 400A8000
R4 = 00000648, R5 = 00000001, R6 = 00000648, R7 = 00000064
R8 = 00000800, R9 = 00000000, R10= 01000008, R11= 00000000
R12= 00000000
SP(R13)= 20008000, MSP= 20008000, PSP= 00000000, R14(LR) = FFFFFFFF
XPSR = 01000000: APSR = nzcvq, EPSR = 01000000, IPSR = 000 (NoException)
CFBP = 00000000, CONTROL = 00, FAULTMASK = 00, BASEPRI = 00, PRIMASK = 00
J-Link>s
20001100:  09 49              LDR     R1, [PC, #+0x24]
J-Link>s
00000140:  FE E7              B       #-0x04
J-Link>
```

here is processor jump to address that located in flash area -  `0x00000140`.
Not to at `0x20000102` as expected.
Hex files of both cases are similar one in one.
It looks like I need to check what difference of results executing of first instructions:

```
00000100:  09 49              LDR     R1, [PC, #+0x24]
```

maybe somebody already faced it, and tell an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LDR` instruction generates a fault while executing from RAM. Most default fault handlers look like this:

```
B .
```

You need to look at the fault registers for more information. But since your original RAM seem to start at `0x20004000`, there might be no RAM at address `0x20001000`.

You can try a linker file like this:

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x20004000, LENGTH = 8K
    RAM (rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20006000, LENGTH = 8K
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me!